# How can I find the sum $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^3+n}$

Tags: calculus

Find the sum
$$T=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^3+n}.$$
When I was calculating $T$,
it comes to $$\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n-1}\zeta (2n+1)$$ such that
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^3+n}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{n^{2k}}=\sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k-1}\zeta (2k+1)=T_1.$$
But I can't calculate $T_1$ and I have no idea how to do it. Can you help me to find sum $T$?

Comment: Please avoid math-only titles. These are discouraged for technical reasons - see [Guidelilnes for good use of MathJax on question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: Try to do partial fractions on $\mathrm{\frac1{n(n^2+1)}}$ and split up the sums?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. A partial fraction decomposition gives
$$
\frac{1}{n^3+n}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 (n-i)}-\frac{1}{2 (n+i)},\quad n\ge 1,
$$ then one may use the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula) expansion\begin{align}
\psi(z + 1)
&= -\gamma + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + z}\right), \qquad z \neq -1, -2, -3, \cdots
\end{align}
to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Maple says $T = \operatorname{Re}\big(\psi(i)\big) + \gamma \approx 0.6719$ where $\psi$ is the digamma function and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.